# I'm getting a Null pointer exception in my code because of the hashmap not being filled or maybe not

Tags: java, interface, nullpointerexception

I was given this exercise:
Implement the following class that loads and prints a set of data values.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
public class MyLoader {
    public void loadAndPrintValues(Iterator<String> keysToLoad, Data data, Printer printer) {

        // Load data values like this:
        // String value = data.loadValue(key);

        // Print loaded data value like this:
        // printer.printEntry(key, value);
    }
}
```

However when I did the exercise I got a `NullPointerException`, probably from the `while (keysToLoad.hasNext())` or from the `key = keysToLoad.next();`.  I assume I got the exception because "data" was not getting filled but I can't figure out how to do it.  Here is my code and error message

```
public interface Data{
    //I made this method
     public void makeEntry(String key, String value);
    //given
     public String loadValue(String key);
}

public interface Printer {
     public void displayEntry(String key, String value);
}

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyLoader implements Data, Printer {
    Data data; // = new MyLoader();
    Printer printer; // = new MyLoader();
    Iterator<String> iter; // = new MyLoader();

      String key = "";
String value = "";

HashMap<String, String> ht = new HashMap<String, String>();

public MyLoader(){
//  this.database = null;
//  this.key = null;
//  this.value = null;
//  this.ht = null;
//  this.iter = null;
    System.out.println("now in the constructor");
}

public MyLoader(Iterator<String> iter, Data data, Printer printer){
    this.data = data;
    this.printer = printer;
    this.iter = iter;
}

public void loadAndPrintValues(Iterator<String> keysToLoad, Data data, Printer printer) {
    try {
        if (ht.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("ht is empty");
            throw new NullPointerException("Database is empty."); 
        }else {
            this.data = data;
        }
           while (keysToLoad.hasNext()){               
           // Load data values like this:
           key = keysToLoad.next();
           value = data.loadValue(key);
           // Print loaded data value like this:
           printer.printEntry(key, value);
       }
    }catch (NullPointerException npe){
        System.out.println("caught null pointer ");
        System.out.println(npe.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void makeEntry(String key, String value){
    ht.put(key, value);
}

@Override
public void printEntry(String key, String value) {  
        System.out.println("[" + key + " : " + value + "]");
}

@Override
public String loadValue(String key) {
    System.out.println("loadValue:" + key);
    if(this.ht.containsKey(key))            
        return this.ht.get(key);
    else {
        System.out.println("No key in database.");
        throw new NullPointerException("No key in data."); 
    }
}

}

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    MyLoader mdbl = new MyLoader();

    mdbl.makeEntry("0", "zero");
    mdbl.makeEntry("1", "One");
    mdbl.makeEntry("2", "Two");
    mdbl.makeEntry("3", "Three");

    mdbl.loadAndPrintValues(mdbl.iter, mdbl.data, mdbl.printer);

    }
    catch(NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "*I got a NullPointerException, probably from the...*" Your stacktrace will tell you *exactly* which line the exception occurred at. Please post your stacktrace.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of your null pointer?

Comment: Exercise is given for reason, for you to learn language. you need to learn debugging. You got the answers here but debugging it would have helped you instead

Comment: I did try to do this exercise by myself for a while but I'm not getting a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

`mdbl.iter` is never assigned a value, i.e. is `null` (by default, since you are using the `MyLoader` constructor without arguments in which `iter` is not assigned). So when you pass it to a method that tries to do operations on it, you naturally get a `NullPointerException` (not an error).

You should not have

```
try{ /* ... */ } catch (NullPointerException npe){ /* ... */ }
```

blocks because any decent IDE will allow you to get to the line where the exception was thrown with one click, which is not the case if you catch the exception and simply print a message to `System.out`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing null values for Iterator, Data and Printer parameter of the method **loadAndPrintValues()** which will result in **NullPointerException**.

Comment: So maybe then the question I need to ask is how do I assign all the parameters (mdbl.iter, Data, & Printer) values?

Answer (score 0):

in this line 
mdbl.loadAndPrintValues(mdbl.iter, mdbl.data, mdbl.printer);
you didn't initialize the mdbl.data and mdbl.printer

Answer (score 0):

Never ever catch a NullPointerException. Remove the catch block with NullPointerException, run it and then post the stack trace.